# How to share a specific image within a web page on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share

Users of a web application have the option of previewing some images. When they click on a specific link, a lightbox opens up with that image in it. The image will, of course, have a fixed URL. I wish to allow them to share only that specific photo, not the entire page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript SDK and use the feed dialog by invoking the [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) method.  Using this method, you can specify the link, title, description, etc.

As a side note, you will need to set up a facebook application to use this method, but your users will not actually have to authorize the app to use this.